# Raw String to normal string javascript

Tags: javascript, string, encoding, decoding

Normal String assignment:

```
var str1 = "\320";
console.log(str1);    //   "Ð"
```

Raw String assignment:

```
var str2 = String.raw`\320`;
console.log(str2);    //   "\320"
```

In raw string, the backslashes are not interpreted. I need to interpret them so that "\320" will become "Ð". Should I have to convert the raw string to normal String. If so, How? If not so, what else should I do and how do I do?

Comment: in my use case, I dont assign values for string, I get it as a raw string dynamically. Thats why i want to convert it, since it is not behaving as a normal string behaves. (interpreting the escapes)

Comment: _“since it is not behaving as a normal string behaves”_ - well yeah that is kinda the purpose of _raw_ … https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Raw_strings

Comment: I know that.. I dont have the control on how I get the values.. I just get these values as raw string and I have to process them.. Hence the question.. @CBroe

Comment: I know it's horrible because it uses `eval`, but at least it illustrates a solution and/or direction to a solution:
`eval(\`var str3 = '${str2}'\`); console.log(str3); # Ð`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is, this code is octal, and since these are mapped with linguistic symbols, javascript interpretes it when defining new string.
what you can do is make a map of all the symbols you require with their key as actual string and value as actual symbol.

for ex -

```
var map = {
    "\\320": "\320"
}

console.log(map);
```

now you can search you text in the map and get the required value.

```
 var str2 = String.raw`\320`;
 var s = map[str2];
 console.log(s);
```

to make the map, try this - 
visit this site - https://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/

and run this code on console

```
 // for latin
 var tbody = document.getElementById("latin");
 var trs = tbody.children;
 var map = {};
 for(i=1;i<trs.length;i++) {
    console.log(trs[i].children[6].innerText);
    key = trs[i].children[6].innerText;
    value = trs[i].children[1].innerText;
    map[key] = value;
 }
```

now console map, stringify it, and paste the string in your code and parse it.
I have done this only for latin, similarly do this for other elements also.

Comment: Yup they are indeed octal values, but I get these values dynamically, so I wouldn't know the actual symbol beforehand.

Comment: No, you wouldn't, so you will have to store all of them.

Comment: Sorry.. but how do I create a map without values? Keys are the raw strings..  How will I assign the values??

Comment: @DhamoR - I have edited the answer to make map, try that.

Comment: ya it is the only solution right now. But this requires complex code for me since, I will get strings with octal values with alphabets, with regular integers, separated by spaces, without spaces in between them.. Have to take care of all such scenarios making it complex..

Comment: I wonder, in python, we have a library called codecs that will take care of all these in just a function call. Do you know any equivalent library or functionality in javascript or jquery?

Comment: @DhamoR I don't know about any such library in javascript as of now. Let me know if you don't find anything, will try to write it.

Comment: ya that would be of great help.. Another problem is that I have octal values like \201 \202 \223 which dont have a character entry in the website https://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/ and I think these values that dont have a character in the map are combining characters (some characters take 3 bytes or 2 bytes together to make a character right?)

Answer (score 1):

Question is a couple of months old, but I think this answer is your best bet, yet. Transforming escape sequences from raw strings is very much doable with ES6 `String.fromcodepoint(<hex-value>)`. I'm in the middle of writing an NPM package which deals with this exact scenario.

First, you need a regular expression which matches all escape sequences in your string. I've used [this as a reference](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) for all the different ones. (I use a raw string for this to avoid spamming backslashes)

```
let [single, ...hex] = String.raw`
  \\[bfnrtv0'"\\]
  \\x[a-fA-F0-9]{2}
 (\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4}){1,}
  \\u\{([0-9a-fA-F]{1,})\}`
  .split("\n").slice(1).map(cur => cur.trim());

let escapes = new RegExp(`(${[single].concat(hex).join("|")})`, "gm"),

    // We need these for later when differentiating how we convert the different escapes.
    uniES6  = new RegExp(`${hex.pop()}`);
    single  = new RegExp(`${single}`);
```

Now you can match all the escapes; reserved single characters, extended ASCII range, ES6 "Astral" unicode hexadecimals and surrogate pairs. (except octals because they're deprecated, but you can always add it back). The next step is writing a function which can replace the code points with the corresponding symbols. First a switch-like function for singles:

```
const singleEscape = seq =>
  (() => ({
    "\\b"  : "\b",
    "\\f"  : "\f",
    "\\n"  : "\n",
    "\\r"  : "\r",
    "\\t"  : "\t",
    "\\v"  : "\v",
    "\\0"  : "\0",
    "\\'"  : "\'",
    "\\\"" : "\"",
    "\\\\" : "\\"
  }[seq]))();
```

Then we can rely on ES6 `fromcodepoint` to deal with the rest which are all hexadecimals.

```
const convertEscape = seq => {

  if (single.test(seq)) 
    return singleEscape(seq);

  else if (uniES6.test(seq))
    return String.fromCodePoint(`0x${seq.split("").slice(3, -1).join("")}`);

  else
    return String.fromCodePoint.apply(
      String, seq.split("\\").slice(1).map(pt => `0x${pt.substr(1)}`)
    );

}
```

Lastly, we tie it all together with a **tagged template literal function** named `normal`. I do not know why you need a raw string, but here you can have access to the raw string and put any additional logic while still resulting in a string where escape sequences are properly parsed.

```
const normal = (strings, ...values) => strings.raw
    .reduce((acc, cur, i) => acc += (values[i-1] || "") + cur, "")
    .replace(escapes, match => convertEscape(match));
```